# Is there a measurable isomorphism ${\mathbb C}\to {\mathbb C}_p$?

Tags: galois-theory

Let $p$ be a prime and ${\mathbb C}_p$ be the completion of the algebraic closure $\overline{{\mathbb Q}_p}$. This field is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$. Both fields come with natural absolute values but have very different topologies. There are no continuous field isomorphisms, but that does not exclude  Borel-measurable ones (measurable in both directions, that is). Do those exist?

A related question is the question for measurable automorphisms of $\mathbb C$. Are there more than the complex conjugation?

Comment: Concerning the last question: $\mathbb{C}$ is Polish hence by Banachs theorem every (Baire/Borel)-measurable homomorphism is automatically continuous.

Comment: It seems that the topology of $\mathbb{C}_p$ is Polish too (I have not proved it). Look in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/238809/is-every-polish-ring-topology-on-mathbbc-defined-by-an-absolute-value (third paragraph). Thus the Borel isomorphisms are continuous too in this case.

Answer (score 9):

$\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb C_p$ are separable complete metric spaces (Polish spaces).  They are Polish groups under addition.  A Borel-measurable homomorphism between Polish groups is continuous.  (Sometimes called "[automatic continuity](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-symbolic-logic/article/abs/automatic-continuity-of-group-homomorphisms/B6AB3A84B7C5C59F7CF885AEC780FA72)".) So any such Borel isomorphism must be a homeomorphism.  But $\mathbb C$ is connected while $\mathbb C_p$ is totally disconnected, so they are not homeomorphic.  We did not require field isomorphism, only group isomorphism for addition.

Comment: Next, you could try to determine whether $\mathbb C_2$ and $\mathbb C_3$ are connected by a Borel isomorphism.